# How to get keys (pids) of registered via Register children

Tags: elixir

I want to use `Registry` module to register dynamically created children processes. 
So I added registry into my supervisor tree:

```
def init([]) do
  children = [
    supervisor(Registry, [:unique, :my_registry]),
    supervisor(MyManager, []),
    # ...
  ]
  opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MySupervisor]
  supervise(children, opts)
end
```

Registration of children happens like this:

```
def start_link(%{id: id}) do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: {:via, Registry, {:my_registry, id}})
end
```

So, my questions is – how to get all keys (children pids) in my Registry.
I tried to use `Registry.keys\2`, but without success.

```
def get_registry_pid do
  Supervisor.which_children(MySupervisor)
  |> Enum.filter(fn {id, _, _, _} -> id == Registry end)
  |> List.first
  |> elem(1) # get a Regisry pid from a tuple {id, pid, type, modules}
end
Registry.keys(:my_registry, get_registry_pid()) # returns []
# but 
Registry.lookup(:my_registry, id) # returns PID as expected
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @Dmitry I don't think keys is meant to get all keys of all processes in the Registry. It's for all keys that a specific PID is registered under. Check out the example in the documentation of `Registry.keys/2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dogbert. But it's not clear for me what is that process PID in my case? Is it a Supervisor pid, which runs this Registry? I checked the documentation and source code, but still confused.

Comment: It seems like that's the PID of the process that was registered to that Registry. In this case, that's the GenServer. If you pass the PID of the GenServer that was started, you should get back its `id`. (I may be wrong though.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a little late but I just came across this issue myself. There seems to be no official way to do this but digging through the `Registry` source and reading something about `:erts` I came up with the following solution:

```ruby
defmodule MyApp.Sensor.Registry do
  @doc """
  Lists all the registered sensors from the registry.
  """
  @spec list_sensors!(module) :: [{String.t(), pid, any}]
  def list_sensors!(registry \\ __MODULE__) do
    try do
      # The args for `lookup_element` are taken from the private function
      # `info/1` from the `Registry` module.
      {_kind, _partitions, table, _pid_ets, _} =
        :ets.lookup_element(registry, -1, 2)

      # select_all is the result of `:ets.fun2ms(&(&1))` which works from iex
      # but not when compiled for reasons beyond my comprehension
      select_all = [{:"$1", [], [:"$1"]}]
      :ets.select(table, select_all)
    catch
      :error, :badarg ->
        raise ArgumentError, "#{inspect(registry)} is not running"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How is this not a `Registry` feature?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you need to extract all registered keys from a given `Registry`.

Since Elixir 1.9.0 this can be achieved via `Registry.select/2` as follows:

```
Registry.select(your_registry, [{{:"$1", :_, :_}, [], [:"$1"]}])
```

This will return the list of all known keys.

For more information on this function, here are the specs of [Registry.select/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Registry.html#select/2) on Hexdocs.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more, at least as of Elixir 1.11.0. Instead, [per this example](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Registry.html#select/2-examples), you can do:

`Registry.select(your_registry, [{{:"$1", :_, :_}, [], [:"$1"]}])`

Comment: So says the documentation, it must have changed recently or I just mistyped it in the first place. I'll update my answer and thank you.